# Rename a file while uploading

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, file-upload

I am using Drag and Drop version of a file uploader which is available at: https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader

But its uploading the file with real name instead of renaming it. I want to rename the file while its being uploaded.

This is the ajax_upload_file.php:

```
<?php
    include('class.uploader.php');

    $uploader = new Uploader();
    $data = $uploader->upload($_FILES['files'], array(
        'limit' => 10, //Maximum Limit of files. {null, Number}
        'maxSize' => 10, //Maximum Size of files {null, Number(in MB's)}
        'extensions' => null, //Whitelist for file extension. {null, Array(ex: array('jpg', 'png'))}
        'required' => false, //Minimum one file is required for upload {Boolean}
        'uploadDir' => '../uploads/', //Upload directory {String}
        'title' => array('name'), //New file name {null, String, Array} *please read documentation in README.md
        'removeFiles' => true, //Enable file exclusion {Boolean(extra for jQuery.filer), String($_POST field name containing json data with file names)}
        'replace' => false, //Replace the file if it already exists  {Boolean}
        'perms' => null, //Uploaded file permisions {null, Number}
        'onCheck' => null, //A callback function name to be called by checking a file for errors (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
        'onError' => null, //A callback function name to be called if an error occured (must return an array) | ($errors, $file) | Callback
        'onSuccess' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded | ($files, $metas) | Callback
        'onUpload' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
        'onComplete' => null, //A callback function name to be called when upload is complete | ($file) | Callback
        'onRemove' => null //A callback function name to be called by removing files (must return an array) | ($removed_files) | Callback
    ));

    if($data['isComplete']){
        $files = $data['data'];

        echo json_encode($files['metas'][0]['name']);
    }

    if($data['hasErrors']){
        $errors = $data['errors'];
        echo json_encode($errors);
    }

    exit;
?>
```

Upload class file is really large so I am not pasting it here. You can download the source from the link given above in 30 secs. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: When your file is up to the PHP,then you will use the `move_uploaded_file`right?by that time you can "rename" you file(s)

Comment: "
'title' => array('name'), //New file name {null, String, Array} *please read documentation in README.md"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to the docs of this plugin:

- **title** New file name

  - **null** Uploads with original file name
  - **String** Custom file name | use: auto, name, {{random}}, {{file_name}}, {{file_size}}, {{timestamp}}, {{date}}, {{extension}}, {{.extension}}
  - **Array**

    - **String** Custom file name | use: auto, name, {{random}}, {{file_name}}, {{file_size}}, {{timestamp}}, {{date}}, {{extension}}, {{.extension}}
    - **Number** Random name length

So, you need to choose what type of name you want. I suggest using random names, the usage is:

```
$data = $uploader->upload($_FILES['files'], array(
        // ... Other options...
        'title' => array('{{random}}{{.extension}}', 32),
        // ... More options...
));
```

That way you create a 32 caracter random name with respective file extension.

Comment: Thanks.. it did the job :)